# deleting alias from file using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, alias, ip-address

I created a ping sweep program that saves gotten IP to a file called hosts. Then, I wanted to delete my own IP address from the file without knowing what my IP address is, so I tried doing the following:

```
    alias ownip='hostname -I'
    sed ownip ./host
```

This did not work, resulting in the following error:

```
    sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `o'
```

So how can I remove my own IP from the file?

Comment: Can you provide a sample line from the output file?

Comment: ***.***.***.107, or should I put out the whole IP address? It is all IP addresses, no more

Comment: Matching the IP means also knowing what *not* to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input "host" file is just a file where each line is an IP address and you want to remove all IP addresses output by `hostname -I` from this file, try this:

```
sed -i "$(hostname -I | sed 's/\([.:[:xdigit:]]\{1,\}\)/\/\1\/d;/g')" ./host
```

The sed inside the command subsitution that hostname is piped to just converts the IP addresses output by hostname into sed delete commands for the outer sed. Sed's `i` flag tells sed to overwrite the file you give it. You might want to run it without this flag first to make sure the output is correct or give `i` an argument which tells sed to create a backup of the input file with that argument as a suffix, e.g. `-i'~'` will produce a backup called `host~`. If your version of sed doesn't have this flag, you can write to a temporary file and overwrite the original:

```
sed "$(hostname -I | sed 's/\([.:[:xdigit:]]\{1,\}\)/\/\1\/d;/g')" ./host > /tmp/newhost && mv /tmp/newhost ./host
```

I think this is what `i` does behind the scenes anyway.

If you really want to use an alias, note that aliases are only [textually substituted when they are the first command word(s)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03_01) in a command, so in your original example you would need to use command substitution, i.e. $(ownip), to give sed the output of actually executing that alias. Your error message means sed is trying to use "ownip" as its script, in which case is complains because sed has no 'o' command.

Answer (score 0):

i use :

```
ip a | grep inet | awk '{print $2}'
```

if you don't want your local address use an additional `grep -v 127`.

Comment: Where's the part that removes it from the file?

Answer (score 0):

I would modify your alias slightly to `trim` the whitespaces and then use your alias `ownip` to generate the delete command as well:

```
alias ownip='hostname -I | xargs'
sed -e "$(ownip | sed -e 's/[.]/[.]/g;s|.*|/&/d;|')" yourhostsfile
```